# ldap integration into Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, ldap

I'm 'new' to Symfony and having issues with LDAP. I am trying to secure a few pages to users that can authenticate via their LDAP credentials. Just a 'did they sign in OK' check... no more interaction than that:

I'm reading the docs at

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/ldap.html

I've done as instructed but I cannot see my login page.

I don't even want to worry about LDAP, I just want to see my login page at this point, but I keep redirecting to my login page.. that never loads and redirects to... my login page

Here's my config bits and bobs:

#### security.yml

```
security:
always_authenticate_before_granting:  true
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, my_ldap]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: dc=mycustomdc,dc=com
            search_dn: "cn=read-only-admin,dc=mycustomdc,dc=com"
            search_password: password
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: uid

firewalls:
    main:

        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: controlpanel_login
            service: ldap
            dn_string: 'uid={username},dc=mycustomdc,dc=com'
```

#### services.yml

```
services:
ldap:
    class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient'
    arguments:
        - myservicepath
        - 389         # port
        - 3           # version
        - false       # SSL
        - true        # TLS
```

FYi: 'controlpanel_login' is a path defined in my bundles routing.yml

I'll worry about talking to my server at some point, how can I just see my login form for now?

=======

UPDATE:
I changed form_login_ldapto http_basic_ldap and I got a user/pass prompt, similar to what I'd see with htacess auth. (not sure what that's called).

Anyhoo so I'm happy to just use that (just for an internal app thing).
but if anyone has an idea what was wrong previously, I'll listen... as leanring SF2 is important..

Comment: Make sure the `/controlpanel_login` is reachable anonymously via firewall config.

Comment: What does your `access_control` section of your security config look like?

Comment: access_control:
        # any one can get to / or /login, but only known users can get to /admin
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }